# Couchbase crud operation using spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, couchbase

I am trying to store data in couchbase and then fetching it but I am not getting success in fetching bucket from couchbase in the jsp page. I'm using spring MVC.

This is my code for fetching data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class ="display" align="center">
        <form method="post">

            <table id="bk_tbl" cellpadding="20px" cellspacing="20px">
                <tr>
                    <th>BOOK NAME </th>
                    <th>AUTHOR NAME </th>
                    <th>ADDRESS </th>
                    <th>CONTACT </th>
                </tr>
                <%
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Hi c...");
                        /* CouchbaseClient c = ConnectionManager.instance().getClient();
                        */
                        //String n1ql="SELECT * FROM `BOOKS` WHERE META().id LIKE 'bk%'"; 
                        Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("127.0.0.1");
                        Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("Book", "root123");

                        String n1ql="select * from `Book`";
                        N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(n1ql));

                        System.out.println("Before row : "+result);
                        for (N1qlQueryRow row : result) {
                            System.out.println("After row : ");
                            System.out.println("row : "+row);
                            String strJson=row.toString();
                            System.out.println("strJson : "+strJson);
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                            String strBucket = jsonObj.getString("Book");
                            JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(strBucket);
                            String bk_name = jsonObj1.getString("fname");
                            String bk_author = jsonObj1.getString("aname");
                            String bk_address = jsonObj1.getString("address");
                            String bk_contact = jsonObj1.getString("contact");

                %>
                           <tr>
                               <td><%=bk_name %></td>
                               <td><%=bk_author %></td>
                               <td><%=bk_address %></td>
                               <td><%=bk_contact %></td>
                           </tr>
                <%
                      }
                      System.out.println("Bye c...");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                %>
           </table>*emphasized text*
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I get a blank page in the output. Also, it's not throwing any kind of exception or errors

Comment: What is the output of the System.out.println ? Does the stacktrace print something?

Comment: Before row : com.couchbase.client.java.query.DefaultN1qlQueryResult@54feaed6

Comment: Stacktrace prints nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you forgot to create a primary index:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `book-primary-index` ON `Book` USING GSI;
```

If your primary index already exists, check if you really have documents in your database or if the connection string is correct.